# JavaScript - Why is this function declaration created in a function expression "undefined"?

Tags: javascript

I'm just trying to get my head around this function expression.

It seems that if I create a function expression (`p`) that seems to contain a function declaration, the function declaration `a()` returns undefined.

```
var p;
p = function a() { return 'Hello' }

typeof p; // returns 'function'
typeof a; // returns 'undefined'
```

Can anyone explain why this is the case?

And also please let me know if my terminology is off too.

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to do this? Use `function a() { return "Hello" } var p = a;` if you need both, or don't specify the anonymous function with a name.

Comment: @Ian: *"...or don't specify the anonymous function with a name..."* Um... ;-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder What? Other than the function being able to access itself, I don't see a use for giving the anonymous function a name...it's clearly confusing the OP too!

Comment: @Ian: I was just pointing out that if it has a name, it's not anonymous, so saying *"...don't give the anonymous function a name..."* is oxymoronic. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Haha yeah I see I see. Poor wording on my part. I'm just so used to never giving a function expression a name.

Answer (score 5):

It isn't a function declaration. It is a function expression that happens to have a name. The name does not create a variable, but you can see it on the object

```
quentin@raston ~ $ node
> var p;
undefined
> p = function a() { return 'Hello' }
[Function: a]
> typeof p; // returns 'function'
'function'
> typeof a; // returns 'undefined'
'undefined'
> p
[Function: a]
> p.name
'a'
>
```

Comment: Worth noting: the function name will also be available as an identifier inside the function body, so it's possible to call a named function expression recursively.

Comment: Also worth noting that the `name` property of function instances is non-standard.

Answer (score 1):

> It seems that if I create a function expression (p) that seems to contain a function declaration

No. It is a [named function expression](http://kangax.github.io/nfe/), which does not "contain" a [function declaration](http://kangax.github.io/nfe/#expr-vs-decl). The name of the function expression is available as an identifier inside the function's scope (pointing to the function itself), and as the [nonstandard `name` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name).

Comment: (Can't believe nobody brought up the link to kangax' site)

Answer (score -3):

You can think of it as an anonymous function.

The reason that this is valid is because the local function name `a` can be used within the function declaration for recursion, but is not valid outside of this scope.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function

Comment: *"You have created an anonymous function declaration."* No, he/she hasn't. First, it's not anonymous. Second, it's not a declaration. It's a *named function expression*. (Function declarations and function expressions are different things; JavaScript has both. You know it's an expression if it's used as a right-hand value.) You're quite correct that the `a` is in scope within the function, but not outside it, though. (Not my downvote, btw.)

Comment: Sorry, my terminology might be off - I was aiming to get across the gist of the problem. How would you describe it?