# Javascript functions like "var foo = function bar() ..."?

Tags: javascript, function

The code goes like this (The syntax may seem odd but as far as I know, there is nothing wrong with it. Or is there?)

```
var add=function addNums(a, b) {                     
   return a+b;
 }                     
 alert("add: "+ add(2,3));           // produces 5
 alert("addNums: "+addNums(2,3));        // should also produce 5
```

`addNums()` is declared as a function. So, when I pass the parameters to it, it should also return the result.

Then, why am I not getting the second alert box?

Comment: That doesn't look like valid javascript to me.

Comment: @Matthew, In what way?

Comment: might be because addNums() is defined at run-time and not at parse-time, and its not visible outside it's scope

Comment: See also [JavaScript - Why is this function declaration created in a function expression “undefined”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16288046/1048572)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You are seeing a [named function expression (NFE)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function#Named_function_expression).

An anonymous function expression is where you assign a function without a name to a variable<sup>1</sup>:

```
var add = function () {
  console.log("I have no own name.");
}
```

A named function expression is where you assign a named function to a variable (surprise!):

```
var add = function addNums() {
  console.log("My name is addNums, but only I will know.");
}
```

The function's name is only available within the function itself. This enables you to use recursion without necessarily knowing the "outside name" of the function - even without having to set one in the first place (think callback functions).

The name you choose *shadows* an existing name, so if another `addNums` is defined elsewhere it will not be overridden. This means you can use any name you like without fear for scoping problems or breaking anything.

In the past you would have used [`arguments.callee`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/callee) to refer to a function inside itself without knowing its name. But support for that is being removed from JavaScript<sup>2</sup>, so NFEs are the correct way to do this nowadays.

Here is a lot of stuff to read on the topic: http://kangax.github.io/nfe/

---

<sup>1</sup> Assigning it to a variable is not necessary, it just serves as an example to distinguish it from a plain function declaration. It could be any other context where JS expects an expression (a function argument, for example).

<sup>2</sup> You will receive an error if you have [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode) in effect and try to use `arguments.callee`.

Comment: +1 for explaining why and where you would use a named function expression.

Comment: @Tomalak Your answer helped a lot. Thanks for the link too :)

Answer (score 5):

### The problem

You are using a [named function expression](http://kangax.github.io/nfe/) - and a function expression's name is not available outside of that function's scope:

```
// Function statement
function statement() {
    console.log("statement is a type of " + typeof statement);
}
statement();
console.log("statement is a type of " + typeof statement);
```

results in:

```
statement is a type of function
statement is a type of function
```

whereas:

```
// Function expression with a name
var expression = function namedExpression() {
    console.log("namedExpression is a type of " + typeof namedExpression);
};

expression();
// namedExpression();  // uncommenting this will cause an exception
console.log("expression is a type of " + typeof expression);
console.log("namedExpression is a type of " + typeof namedExpression);
```

will produce:

```
namedExpression is a type of function
expression is a type of function
namedExpression is a type of undefined
```

### The solution

Depending on what you are trying to do, you want do do one of the following:

- Change your function declaration to use a statement and then alias your function:

  ```
  function addNums(a, b) {
      return a + b;
  }

  var add = addNums;
  ```
- Alias both names to your expression:

  ```
  var add = addNums = function addNums(a, b) {
      return a + b;
  };
  ```

### Why does JavaScript do things this way?

Named function expressions are useful because they let you reference a function inside itself and they give you a name to look at in a debugger.  However, when you use a function as a value you don't generally want parts of it leaking into the enclosing scope.  Consider:

```
(function setup() {
    var config = retrieveInPageConfig();
    if (config.someSetting) {
        performSomeOtherSetup();
    }
    kickOffApplication();
})();
```

This is a perfectly licit use of a function expression - in such a case you would not expect the name `setup` to leak into the enclosing scope. Assigning a named function expression to a variable is just a special case of this, that just happens to *look* like a function statement declaration.

Answer (score 4):

`addNums` is **only available in the scope of the newly-defined function**.

> Quite obviously, when a function expression has a name (technically —
>   Identifier), it is called a **named function expression**. What you’ve
>   seen in the very first example — var bar = function foo(){}; — was
>   exactly that — a named function expression with foo being a function
>   name. An important detail to remember is that **this name is only**
>    **available in the scope of a newly-defined function**; specs mandate that
>   an identifier should not be available to an enclosing scope.

Read more detail form **[this article](http://kangax.github.io/nfe/)**.

Answer (score 1):

You should either declare as named function:

```
function addNums(){

}
```

or assign function to the variable:

```
var add= function(){// your code }
```

The reason why addNum() doesn't return anything is because it's not added to the global scope with the way you declare it.

Comment: @c 2 I don't think there is anything wrong with this kind of declaration too.

Answer (score 1):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3UmKJ/)

```
function addNums(a, b) {
   return a+b;
}
var add = addNums;
alert("add: "+ add(2,3));
alert("addNums: "+addNums(2,3));
```

Answer (score 1):

I have added your code in my test web app and works fine for me. Here is the code. Would you please share the more details of your code/app?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="JavascriptTest.aspx.cs" Inherits="GetGridViewColumnValue.JavascriptTest" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var add = function addNums(a, b) {
            return a + b;
        }
        alert("add: " + add(2, 3));           // produces 5
        alert("addNums: " + addNums(2, 3));

     </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Cheers!!!

Comment: is this code working? well, for me its not and for everyone else here too!

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following code:

```
var f = function g() {
    // function
};
```

The `g` will be access only in the function itself, and its needed when you want to use the function
by itself, for writing recursive functions. For example, you want the `factorial` function:

```
var f = function factorial(x) {
    if (x <= 1) return 1;

    // here we want to use the function itself
    return x * factorial(x - 1);
};

console.log(f(5));
```

However, its really needed as you can access the function itself by `arguments.callee`:

```
// note that the function has not any name
var f = function (x) {
    if (x <= 1) return 1;

    // here we want to use the function itself
    return x * arguments.callee(x - 1);
};

console.log(f(5));
```

Answer (score 1):

I've slightly modified your code:

```
var add = function addNums(a, b){
             return a+b;
}
console.log(add);
console.log(typeof(add));
console.log("add: "+ add(2,3));           // produces 5
console.log("addNums: "+addNums(2,3));
```

And then proceeded to run it inside of node.js to get this output:

```
[Function: addNums]
function
add: 5

/home/mel/l.js:44
console.log("addNums: "+addNums(2,3));
                        ^
ReferenceError: addNums is not defined (... backtrace)
```

Normally, a variable assigned an inline anonymous method would print out `[Function]` when called with `console.log(var);` Here `console.log(add);` results in the name of the function also being printed.

So it's not like your addNums declaration is invalid or not used, it's simply scoped to be bound to the variable add.

Answer (score 0):

addNums is not a function in the global namespace..
It's an function defined only within the assignment operator..

if you want to have access to it try the follow:

```
  function addNums(a, b) 
  {                     
     return a+b;
  } 

  var add = addNums;


  var add = function <---- the function name is add and it's value is a function..
```