# Typescript Definition. Named Function Expression (NFE)

Tags: typescript

I am looking at the following JS which is one of many in the project I am creating a `.d.ts` file for.

`BatchBuffer.js`

```
var Buffer = function(size)
 {

     this.vertices = new ArrayBuffer(size);

     /**
      * View on the vertices as a Float32Array for positions
      *
      * @member {Float32Array}
      */
     this.float32View = new Float32Array(this.vertices);

     /**
      * View on the vertices as a Uint32Array for uvs
      *
      * @member {Float32Array}
      */
     this.uint32View = new Uint32Array(this.vertices);
 };

 module.exports = Buffer;

 Buffer.prototype.destroy = function(){
   this.vertices = null;
   this.positions = null;
   this.uvs = null;
   this.colors  = null;
 };
```

A search on Google [to here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16631708/javascript-functions-like-var-foo-function-bar) tells me that this is a `Named Function Expression (NFE)` but I started to get lost. The module is adding additional confusion.

How would one define this correctly? The name is a bugbear (`BatchBuffer` or `Buffer`) and does this this look accurate?

```
export module BatchBuffer {

    export var vertices: ArrayBuffer;
    export var float32View: number[];
    export var uint32View: number[];

    export function destroy(): void;

}
```

I keep hitting these similar NFE files so for my definition to be accurate, I feel I need advice or confirmation.

Thanks.

*Edited.*

See Ryan's Answer.

Most other classes in the project looked (similar!) to this pseudo for example:

`MyClass.js`

```
function MyClass(something)
{
    /**
     * Some property
     *
     * @member {number}
     */
    this.something = something;
}

MyClass.prototype.constructor = MyClass;
module.exports = MyClass;

MyClass.prototype.hi = function ()
{
}
```

I was assigning meaning to something which appears to be the same. Although the details escape me. To know it is a class suits me fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have here is a class -- it's intended to be instantiated with `new` (you can tell because it assigns a function to a property of `prototype`), and it has properties and a method.

Your file should look something like this:

```
declare class Buffer {
  constructor(size: number);

  vertices: ArrayBuffer;
  float32View: Float32Array;
  uint32View: Float32Array;

  uvs: any; // not sure of type
  colors: any; // not sure of type
  positions: any; // not sure of type

  destroy(): void;
}

// expresses "module.exports = Buffer"
export = Buffer;
```

Comment: Doh! Thank you once again Ryan.