# JavaScript hoisting explanation

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between below snippets?

```
var a = 0;
function b(){
    a = 10;
    return function a(){};
}
b();
console.log(a);  // => 10
```

and

```
var a = 0;
function b(){
    a = 10;
    return
    function a(){};
}
b();
console.log(a);  // => 0
```

It has something to do with JavaScript hoisting, but my understanding of the concept gives exactly the opposite output.

Comment: When using `return ` on a row of itself, it do just that, _return_ and exit the `function b()`. Javascript will auto-add a `;` after it.

Comment: Function declarations are processed before any code is executed (so-called "hoisting"), hence it doesn't matter where they're placed, they're always evaluated.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [Why doesn't a return statement work when the return value is on a new line?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8528557/1048572), [function scoping and hoisting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7506844/1048572) and [Why is this function declaration created in a function expression “undefined”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16288046/1048572)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

```
return function a(){};
```

Here `function ...` is an expression. A *named function expression* to be precise. The `a` here doesn't matter much, it just gives the anonymous function a [`.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name), but it's still just a function expression that you're returning.

```
return 
function a(){};
```

This here is equivalent to:

```
return;
function a(){};
```

Here `function a` is a declaration, not an expression. It is hoisted, creating a local name `a` in the scope, shadowing the outer `a`. I.e. it is equivalent to:

```
function b(){
    var a = function () {};
    a = 10;
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @deceze, Missed to notice that **function a()** in 1st snippet is a function expression, and a function declaration in the 2nd snippet. And, a **Function Expression** is only defined when that line is reached, whereas **Function declaration** is defined as soon as its surrounding function or script is executed.

Answer (score 26):

```
return
function a() {}
```

is same as

```
return;
function a() {}
```

after automatic semicolon insertion.
In second case, function `a` is moved to the top of its scope. The code is same as

```
var a = 0;

function b() {
  function a() {};
  a = 10;
  return;
}
b();
console.log(a);
```

As `a` inside `b()` is inner function and then overriden, it is not accessible from outside of `b()`.

Here is the demo to understand how the hoisting works.

```js
var a = 0;

function b() {
  console.log(a); // function
  a = 10;
  console.log(a); // 10
  return

  function a() {};
}
console.log(b()); // undefined
console.log(a);
```

Comment: Thanks Tushar, but I wanted to know why **function a()** is not hoisted in the 1st snippet while it is being hoisted in 2nd snippet. @deceze explained it well in his answer.

Comment: @SnapADragon Then why this question has more up votes than it?

Comment: coz Tushar's answer may have served others better, but @deceze explained something I was looking for. Satisfactory enough?

Answer (score 1):

**Line-break** may be used instead of **semicolon**.

**This**:

```
var a = 0;
function b(){
    a = 10;
    return // line-break
    function a(){};
}
b();
console.log(a);  // => 0
```

**means** this:

```
var a = 0;
function b(){
    a = 10;
    return; // <-- 'adds this semicolon'
    function a(){};
}
b();
console.log(a);  // => 0
```

If you **need** this **line-break**, you can **do** like **this**:

```
var a = 0;
function b(){
    a = 10;
    return (
        function a(){}
    )
}
b();
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score -1):

Let's assume.

You are playing cricket. bowler is on the way and you just hit your bat on the air.

Would it be shot? No!

So if we assume hoisting is cricket, therefore there is no sense to hit ball till bowler does not throw the ball

Quick Example:

Hoisted

```
console.log('batsman hit but ', ballStatus()); // batsman hit but  true


function ballStatus() {
    return true;
}
```

Non-Hoisted

```
 console.log('batsman hit but ', ballStatus()); // Uncaught TypeError: ballStatus is not a function

 var ballStatus = function() {
    return true;
 }
```