# Global Functions in ReactJS tells me 'not a function'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a GlobalFunction.js file with this.

```
function day(day) {
  switch(day) {
    case 0:
      return "Sunday";
    case 1:
      return "Monday";
    case 2:
      return "Tuesday";
    case 3:
      return "Wednesday";
    case 4:
      return "Thursday";
    case 5:
      return "Friday";
    case 6:
      return "Saturday";
  }
}
function month(month) {
  switch(month) {
    case 0:
      return "January";
    case 1:
      return "February";
    case 2:
      return "March";
    case 3:
      return "April";
    case 4:
      return "May";
    case 5:
      return "June";
    case 6:
      return "July";
    case 7:
      return "August";
    case 8:
      return "September";
    case 9:
      return "October";
    case 10:
      return "November";
    case 11:
      return "December";
  }
}
function styleTime(time) {
  time = time[1].split(':');
  // fetch
  var hours = Number(time[0]);
  var minutes = Number(time[1]);
  var seconds = Number(time[2]);
  // calculate
  var timeValue;
  if (hours > 0 && hours <= 12) {
    timeValue= "" + hours;
  } else if (hours > 12) {
    timeValue= "" + (hours - 12);
  } else if (hours == 0) {
    timeValue= "12";
  }

  timeValue += (minutes < 10) ? ":0" + minutes : ":" + minutes;  // get minutes
  timeValue += (hours >= 12) ? " P.M." : " A.M.";  // get AM/PM
  return timeValue;
}
function nth(d) {
  if (d > 3 && d < 21) return 'th';
  switch (d % 10) {
    case 1:  return "st";
    case 2:  return "nd";
    case 3:  return "rd";
    default: return "th";
  }
}
function styleDate(date) {
  var verifyDay = new Date(date[0]);
  var dayOfWeek = day(verifyDay.getDay()); //prints monday, tuesday, wednesday, etc
  var year = verifyDay.getFullYear(); // prints the year
  var month = month(verifyDay.getMonth());
  var day = verifyDay.getDate();
  var date = day + nth(verifyDay.getDate());
  return dayOfWeek + ", " + month + " " + date + " " + year;
}

export function styleDateTime(dateString) {
  var dateTime = dateString.split(" ");
  return styleDate(dateTime) + " at " + styleTime(dateTime);
}

// default export
export default function() {
    return 'default';
}
```

I import this into a js file like so.

```
import { styleDateTime } from "../GlobalFunctions"
```

I use it like so:

```
{styleDateTime(array.date)}
```

In the styleDate function, it tells me that `day is not a function`. why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because inside `styleDate` method you are creating a new variable with same name as day and that's why you are not able to access the day method. Use a different variable name, it will work.

Write it like this:

```
function styleDate(date) {
  var verifyDay = new Date(date[0]);
  var dayOfWeek = day(verifyDay.getDay()); //prints monday, tuesday, wednesday, etc
  var year = verifyDay.getFullYear(); // prints the year
  var month = month(verifyDay.getMonth());

  // here
  var new_day = verifyDay.getDate();
  var date = new_day + nth(verifyDay.getDate());
  return dayOfWeek + ", " + month + " " + date + " " + year;
}
```

Comment: ahhhh!!! inside of the actual react i would call this.function. That is why i dont get this error. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's because your local `day` variable in `styleDate` is [shadowing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373278/variable-shadowing-in-javascript) the function defined outside of it. Rename it to something else.

If you think it shouldn't be shadowed because it's defined after the first usage, [JavaScript applies hoisting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49873174/javascript-hoisting-explanation) which moves all the declarations to the beginning of the function, setting them to undefined until they are later set.

```
function styleDate(date) {
    ...
    var myDay = verifyDay.getDate(); 
    var date = myDay + nth(verifyDay.getDate());
    ...
```

Comment: ahhhh!!! inside of the actual react i would call this.function. That is why i dont get this error. thanks!