# Variable Hoisting in JS

Tags: javascript

I am a bit confused here in the Variable Hoisting concept. Why does the first `console.log(flag)` outputs `undefined`? Shouldn't it catch the already initialised value of false moving up the scope chain?

```js
var flag = false;
(function(){
    console.log(flag);
    var flag = true; // JavaScript only hoists declarations, not initialisations

    console.log(flag);

    if(flag){
        let name = "John";
        const age = "24";

        console.log(name);
        console.log(age);
    }

    //console.log(name); //ReferenceError: name is not defined ( as name is block scoped here )
    //console.log(age);  //ReferenceError: age is not defined ( as age is block scoped )

})();
```

Comment: `var flag = true` is a separate declaration that shadows `var flag = false`. Since it's a different declaration, you will get the new one. But since the assignment hasn't run yet, you just get `undefined`.

Comment: Also relevant: ['Hoisted' JavaScript Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29667199) [JavaScript hoisting explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49873174) [Javascript function scoping and hoisting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7506844)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here happens following:

Your declaration `var flag = true;` gets hoisted inside of its execution environment. In this case it is your function. Its kinda weird but only the declared variable gets hoisted without the value assignment.

```js
var flag = false;
(function(){
    console.log(flag);
    var flag = true; // JavaScript only hoists declarations, not initializations

    console.log(flag);

    if(flag){
        let name = "John";
        const age = "24";

        console.log(name);
        console.log(age);
    }

    //console.log(name); //ReferenceError: name is not defined ( as name is block scoped here )
    //console.log(age);  //ReferenceError: age is not defined ( as age is block scoped )

})();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for clearing the confusion.

Answer (score 6):

In JS we also have functional scope and since variable name is same in both scopes, the global `flag` gets overridden and because of that the first console.log(flag) outputs undefined. Considering this piece of code :

```
(function(){
console.log(flag);
var flag = true;
})
```

Applying Variable Hoisting concept this will internally become like this:

```
(function(){
var flag=undefined;
console.log(flag);
flag = true;
})
```

You are confused because of the outer scope `flag` variable but that will be overridden with the functional scope `flag` variable because of same naming conventions used.

Answer (score 3):

The `flag` is hosted inside [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately_invoked_function_expression)

```
var flag = false;
(function(){
    var flag; // undefined
    console.log(flag);
    flag = true; // JavaScript only hoists declarations, not initializations

    console.log(flag);

    if(flag){
        let name = "John";
        const age = "24";

        console.log(name);
        console.log(age);
    }

    //console.log(name); //ReferenceError: name is not defined ( as name is block scoped here )
    //console.log(age);  //ReferenceError: age is not defined ( as age is block scoped )

})();
```

Comment: Because the value of the `flag` at first log is `undefined`. If you want to print `false` then you should remove second `var flag = ` declaration and leave it `flag = `

Comment: Oh, it is because only my flag declaration gets hoisted on top of the function.