# JavaScript basic concept - hoisting

Tags: javascript, this, hoisting

I am using JS from quite a time now but still get stuck in some places with very basic concepts.
Recently going through some basic questions I got stuck with this one

```
var employeeId = 'abc123';

function foo() {
    employeeId = '123bcd';
    return;

    function employeeId() {}
}
foo();
console.log(employeeId);
```

O/P : `abc123`

Can someone explain how the output is abc123.
It might be a very basic question but any help will be appreciated.

Comment: this problem is all about scoping. Read more about this [here](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-scope/)

Comment: @Shubham Scoping alone is an insufficient explanation here. It's also about the peculiarity of function declaration hoisting which produces the unintuitive outcome here.

Comment: `employeeId` gets hoisted inside of `foo`. When you write `employeeId = "123bcd"` it searches in the current scope (foo) if there is an variable named `employeeId` and yes there is the hoisted function `employeeId`. now you override the function to an string and return nothing.

Comment: @Ifaruki can you elaborate more. Why it is taking value from global scope?

Comment: You did notice [the duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49873322/476) which explains it…?

Comment: @deceze I did but the duplicate question doesn't answer my question

Comment: How exactly doesn't it? `function employeeId` creates a local name `employeeId`, the same as `var employeeId` would. That *shadows* the global variable by the same name, so assigning to `employeeId` inside the function does *not* change the outer variable. Is that clear enough?

Comment: mutating outside variables from inside an function is ugly and not pure. i recommend to read about [pure functions](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/what-is-a-pure-function-in-javascript-acb887375dfe/)  .pure functions helps you to write cleaner code without side effects. its a core principle about functional programming.